# Jqgrid grouping and bindKeys

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I do not know if it's a bug or so should be.
When using grouping and arrows up and down and selected row come to groupField, fails to pass over,  jump to the last row .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of `bindKeys` method come unchanged from jqGrid 4.7. The code don't support data grouping like some other jqGrid options (`multiselect: true` for example). The code just goes to the next sibling row, get its id (which is empty) and try to select the row with empty id. It can't work in the form with data grouping.

So I would just confirm that `bindKeys` don't support grids with data grouping. I will consider to rewrite the code in the future to reduce the number of existing restrictions.

**UPDATE:** I rewrote the code of `bindKeys` method and have posted [the new code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/e4f36228cb892f60706ec6a319a2b30498d4df72) to github just now. It should support data grouping now.